# Não consigo obter de um arquivo JSON a URL da imagem, apesar de ser feito da mesma forma que outros dados que são obtidos corretamente

Tags: java, android, json

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo baseado em outro aplicativo, no caso, o app é um mapa (provido pelas APIs do Google Maps) onde pontos são adicionados mapa e podem ser clicados para exibir mais informações sobre o local, esses dados (nome, descrição e coordenadas geográficas) são obtidas de um arquivo JSON.

> Um vídeo para elucidar melhor o funcionamento da aplicação: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z2oIMFM5ZM

Então, eu gostaria que aquela ImageView onde aparece aquela imagem do GTA V (usada apenas para exemplificar) fosse obtida através de uma URL obtida de um arquivo JSON, assim como os dados citados anteriormente. O Arquivo JSON em questão é este: https://api.myjson.com/bins/ox334

*(Nos códigos a seguir, é possível ver a minha falha tentativa de tentar imitar os códigos que obtiam corretamente os dados (como nome, descrição e coordenadas) no código-fonte do qual usei como base, mas não consegui e não consegui identificar a causa correta do problema e muito menos corrigi-lo...)*

***RESULTADOS OBTIDOS AO DEBUGAR A APLIÇÃO:***
[image: https://imgur.com/a/H2k0CBL]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após ver as imagens acima, perceba que no código do arquivo Pontos.java, "recebeImagem" é o único que não retorna nada ao ser adicionado um breakpoint nele e rodado em debugging, até o próprio "aplicaImagem" retorna a URL que existe lá no JSON, mas eu percebi algo estranho nisso que pode ser visto nas imagens acima, após a linha de "aplicaImagem" no Pontos.java, o breakpoint retorna ao final o aviso "imagem: null", o que é estranho, já que não aparece em outras linhas as quais eu adicionei breakpoints para debugar.

Apesar de tudo eu realmente não sei qual a causa do problema.

**OBS. Inclui partes relevantes do código abaixo, junto com links para tais arquivos Java completos para leitura no PasteBin.**

***OutraActivity.java (A Activity onde a imagem deveria aparecer na ImageView "ImagemLugar"):***
       (OutraActivity.java completa: https://pastebin.com/kwyv9EeY)

```
    private ImageView ImagemLugar;
      ...
    public static ArrayList<Pontos> iwantimage = new ArrayList<>();
       ...
    ImagemLugar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageem);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

     for (int i = 0; i < iwantimage.size(); i++) {
         Pontos pontos = iwantimage.get(i);

         Picasso.get().load(pontos.recebeImagem()).into(ImagemLugar);
    }
    return v;
}
```

**Activity onde dados são obtidos do JSON:** (o arquivo completo: https://pastebin.com/eBZq0nDZ)

```
String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ox334";
  ...
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        ...
            JSONObject objectp = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jArrPoints = objectp.getJSONArray("pontos");

            for (int i =0 ;i<jArrPoints.length();i++) {
                pontos = new Pontos();
                pontos.aplicaNome(jArrPoints.getJSONObject(i).getString("nome"));
                pontos.aplicaPosx(jArrPoints.getJSONObject(i).getString("posx"));
                pontos.aplicaPosy(jArrPoints.getJSONObject(i).getString("posy"));
                pontos.aplicaDescricao( jArrPoints.getJSONObject(i).getString("descricao"));
                pontos.aplicaTipo( jArrPoints.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipo"));
                pontos.aplicaImagem( jArrPoints.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagem"));
                listaitensPontos.add(pontos);
            }
        AbaMapa.listaitens = listaitensPontos;
```

**O Arquivo "Pontos.java", uma ArrayList:** (Pontos.java completo: https://pastebin.com/mVvgWKgm)

```
public class Pontos {
    private String nome;
    private String posx;
    private String posy;
    private String descricao;
    private String tipo;
    private String imagem;

    public Pontos(){}
    public Pontos(String nome, String posx, String posy, String descricao, String tipo){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.posx = posx;
        this.posy = posy;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.imagem = imagem;

    }
    public String recebeNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void aplicaNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String recebePosx() {
        return posx;
    }

    public void aplicaPosx (String posx) {
        this.posx = posx;
    }

    public String recebePosy() {
        return posy;
    }

    public void aplicaPosy (String posy) {
        this.posy = posy;
    }

    public String recebeDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void aplicaDescricao (String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String recebeTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void aplicaTipo (String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String recebeImagem() {
        return imagem;
    }

    public void aplicaImagem (String imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Na linha 83 do arquivo OutraActivity.java, você cria um objeto sem declarar um nome, deveria ser assim

**ImagemLugar imagem = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageem);**

E verifique se o ID do elemento no layout é realmente **imageem**

Comment: @J.PedroA., isso gera um erro ao compilar: "error: cannot find symbol class ImagemLugar"

Comment: @J.PedroA., além de que "ImagemLugar" nessa linha acaba ficando com uma marcação vermelha que detalha o seguinte: "Unknown Class: 'imagem'"

Comment: @J.PedroA., se eu tivesse que apostar, eu diria que o problema é na Pontos.java 

Isso é o que me retorna quando adiciono um breakpoint na linha do "aplicaImagem" em Pontos.java: https://i.imgur.com/7SPv8jw.png